# Use NUnit Assert.Throws method or ExpectedException attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit, assert

I have discovered that these seem to be the two main ways of testing for exceptions:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(()=>MethodThatThrows());

[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
```

Which of these would be best? Does one offer advantages over the other? Or is it simply a matter of personal preference?

Comment: A 3rd option is the fluent style: `Assert.That(() => MethodThatThrows(), Throws.Exception)`

Comment: NUnit version 3 and later no longer support the `ExpectedException` attribute, so for version 3+ only the `Assert.Throws` variant is relevant.

Comment: Why is it so? That Nunit3 decided to drop that support? Was googling around and could not find explanation for it... JUnit still supports this way, doesn't it?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The first allows you to test for more than one exception, with multiple calls:

```
Assert.Throws(()=>MethodThatThrows());
Assert.Throws(()=>Method2ThatThrows());
```

The second only allows you to test for one exception per test  function.

Comment: A test should only test one distinct bit of logic, so wouldn't testing two errors in the same unit test be considered bad practice?

Comment: @SamuelDavis - in general you wouldn't want to test different cases in the same test. However, there may be some use case for multiple `Assert.Throws`.

Comment: Either way, here you get the exception as a parameter, which allows you to assert details in the exception.
Also, using "Expected exception" does not protect you for the same exception type being thrown in another method call. Here, you target the exact method and not the whole test. Even though your test should call very little code, you're never too safe. Especially when code becomes complex and/or exception too generic.
Stuff like "ArgumentNullExceptions" can be thrown a lot and would for example be easily missed using the ExpectedException. Assert.Throws would not miss it.

Answer (score 275):

The main difference is:

`ExpectedException()` attribute makes test passed if exception occurs in *any* place in the test method.
The usage of `Assert.Throws()` allows to specify `exact` place of the code where exception is expected.

NUnit 3.0 drops official support for `ExpectedException` altogether.

So, I definitely prefer to use `Assert.Throws()` method rather than `ExpectedException()` attribute.

Comment: This is by far the correct answer.  Incidentally, Assert.Throws() also returns the exception, which can allow additional inspection of the properties of the exception, if they matter to you.

Comment: Finally answer why I can't get ExpectedException to work .. with version 3.

Comment: Here is the link https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes - ExpectedExceptionAttribute no longer supported.

Comment: To change this to work under NUnit 3.0, change it to [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33895620/3937190)

Answer (score 52):

I prefer `Assert.Throws()` since it allows me to verify and assert other conditions after the exception is thrown.

```
[Test]
[Category("Slow")]
public void IsValidLogFileName_nullFileName_ThrowsExcpetion()
{
    var a = new MyTestObject();

    // the exception we expect thrown from the IsValidFileName method
    var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => a.IsValidLogFileName(""));

    // now we can test the exception itself
    Assert.That(ex.Message == "Blah");
}
```

Comment: This is one of the better answers, it's pretty common that you want to verify that something has entered an errored state after the exception is thrown.

Comment: Good answer! But what's the meaning of `[Category("Slow")]` and `a`?

Comment: You can use Categories to group your tests - it's not needed for this example - in this case "Slow" might mean that want to be able to choose whether or not to run "slow" tests every time or only as part of nightly or weekly runs or something. I believe the "a" was a syntax error technically, but it's just the object that you're testing.

Comment: (+1) Being able to test the exception itself after the Assert.Throws is useful especially with AggregateException and its InnerExceptions collection.

Answer (score 13):

You may also strong type the error you're expecting (like the old attrib version).

```
Assert.Throws<System.InvalidOperationException>(() => breakingAction())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using older version(**<=2.0**) of `NUnit` then you need to use `ExpectedException`.

If you are using **2.5** or later version then you can use `Assert.Throw()`

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes

How to use:
https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5