# TargetInvocationException in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, testing, nsubstitute, targetinvocationexception

I want to write a test checking, whether my abstract classes constructor correctly handles invalid arguments. I wrote a test:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void MyClassCtorTest()
{
    var dummy = Substitute.For<MyClass>("invalid-parameter");
}
```

This test does not pass, because NSubstitute throws a `TargetInvocationException` instead of `ArgumentException`. The actual exception I seek for is actually an `InnerException` of that `TargetInvocationException`. I can write a helper method like:

```
internal static class Util {

    public static void UnpackException(Action a) {

        try {

            a();
        } catch (TargetInvocationException e) {

            throw e.InnerException;
        } catch (Exception) {

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid exception was thrown!");
        }
    }
}
```

But I guess, that there rather should be some kind of general way of solving that problem. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

NSubstitute does not currently have a general way of solving this.

Some other workarounds include manually subclassing the abstract class to test the constructor, or manually asserting on the inner exception rather than using `ExpectedException`.

For example, say we have an abstract class that requires a non-negative integer:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    protected MyClass(int i) {
        if (i < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i", "Must be >= 0");
        }
    }
    // ... other members ...
}
```

We can create a subclass in a test fixture to test the base class constructor:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleFixture {
    private class TestMyClass : MyClass {
        public TestMyClass(int i) : base(i) { }
        // ... stub/no-op implementations of any abstract members ...
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
    public void TestInvalidConstructorArgUsingSubclass()
    {
        new TestMyClass(-5);
    }
    // Aside: I think `Assert.Throws` is preferred over `ExpectedException` now.
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15043731/906
}
```

Alternatively you can still use a mocking framework and assert on the inner exception. I think this is less preferable to the previous option as it is not obvious why we're digging in to the `TargetInvocationException`, but here's an example anyway:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestInvalidConstructorArg()
    {
        var ex = Assert.Throws<TargetInvocationException>(() => Substitute.For<MyClass>(-5));

        Assert.That(ex.InnerException, Is.TypeOf(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)));
    }
```

Comment: How do you "...manually asserting on the inner exception..."?

Comment: @hbob: I've added examples of both approaches. Please let me know if you'd like any more information.

Comment: There's another way. If you have `Dog : AAnimal` and want to test the abstract `AAnimal`,  you create abstract `AAnimalTests` with appropriate tests. Then create a `DogTests : AAnimalTests` class. When its tests are run, they operate on a concrete implementation (`Dog`), so you don't need a fake. Gets a little messy when there are multiple implementations (`Cat`, `Horse`, `Bird`, etc.) because the "same" tests are run for every implementation, but maybe that's not a bad thing. I don't know if this is "best practice", but I've been doing it for a while. What do you think?