# NUnit 3.0 and Assert.Throws

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am writing some unit tests with NUnit 3.0 and, unlike v2.x, `ExpectedException()` has been removed from the library.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014461/should-i-use-nunits-assert-throws-method-or-expected-exception-attribute) answer, I can definitely see the logic in trying to catch specifically where in the test one expects their system to throw an exception (rather than just saying 'anywhere in the test').

However, I tend to be very explicit about my Arrange, Act, and Assert steps and this makes it a challenge.

I used to do something like:

```
[Test, ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
public void Should_not_convert_from_prinergy_date_time_sample1()
{
    //Arrange
    string testDate = "20121123120122";

    //Act
    testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime();

    //Assert
    Assert.Fail("FromPrinergyDateTime should throw an exception parsing invalid input.");
}
```

Now I need to do something like:

```
[Test]
public void Should_not_convert_from_prinergy_date_time_sample2()
{
    //Arrange
    string testDate = "20121123120122";

    //Act/Assert
    Assert.Throws<FormatException>(() => testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime());
}
```

This isn't terrible, but muddies the Act and Assert, in my opinion. (Obviously, for this simple test, it's not hard to follow, but might be more challenging in larger tests).

I've had a colleague suggest I get rid of `Assert.Throws` altogether and just do something like:

```
[Test]
public void Should_not_convert_from_prinergy_date_time_sample3()
{
    //Arrange
    int exceptions = 0;
    string testDate = "20121123120122";

    //Act
    try
    {
        testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime();
    }
    catch (FormatException) { exceptions++;}

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, exceptions);
}
```

Here, I stick with the strict AAA format, but at the expense of even more bloat.

So my question goes out to AAA-style testers: How would you do some sort of exception validation testing like I am trying to do here?

Comment: When tested method has no parameters the Assert can be simplified like this: Assert.Throws<FormatException>(testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime) or Assert.That(testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime, Throws.TypeOf<FormatException>());

Comment: Second part doesn't look that bloated to me?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I see where you're coming from, even though I don't mind combining Act/Assert steps in this case.

The only thing I can think of is to store the actual delegate (here to `FromPrinergyDateTime`) into a variable as the "act" step and then assert it:

```
[Test]
public void Should_not_convert_from_prinergy_date_time_sample2()
{
    //Arrange
    string testDate = "20121123120122";

    //Act
    ActualValueDelegate<object> testDelegate = () => testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime();

    //Assert
    Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.TypeOf<FormatException>());
}
```

I get that the "act" step isn't *really* acting, but rather defining what the action is.  However, it does clearly delineate what action is being tested.

Comment: Ahh, that's pretty slick idea. I was getting hung up on how to separate the two.

Comment: Still not really "acting" though.  Just declaring how you plan to act.

Comment: It's a great answer. I had a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660806/how-to-handle-multiple-exception-testing-in-nunit-3-according-to-arrage-act-asse) to it, which I posted separately. Care to take a look?

Answer (score 27):

In C# 7, there is another option (albeit very similar to the existing answers):

```
[Test]
public void Should_not_convert_from_prinergy_date_time_sample2()
{
    void CheckFunction()
    {
        //Arrange
        string testDate = "20121123120122";

        //Act
        testDate.FromPrinergyDateTime();
    }

    //Assert
    Assert.Throws(typeof(Exception), CheckFunction);
}
```

[Blog post on the subject](http://pmichaels.net/2017/03/14/testing-exceptions-using-arrange-act-assert-pattern-c-7/)

Comment: Upvote because of the "what you can actually do this in c#" factor

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom Attribute in NUnit 3. Here is the sample code how to create `[ExpectedException]` Attribute.(ExpectedExceptionExample Shows how to implement a custom attribute for NUnit)
https://github.com/nunit/nunit-csharp-samples

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the link!

Comment: [ExpectedException] is deprecated in NUnit3. Use the Assert.That/Throws mechanism.

Comment: @RvdK

Can you please let me know what is the difference between Assert.That and Assert.Throws.. I dont really get the difference between both statements as below. Both works for me.. But which is better to use.

`Assert.Throws<DataLayerException>(TestDelegate code, "Message");`

`Assert.That(TestDelegate code, Is.TypeOf<DataLayerException>(), "Message"); `

Comment: @VikranthSanka Assert.That has better readability, the Assert.That reads more natural. But it also has some other benefits: https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/