# How to handle multiple exception testing in nUnit 3 according to Arrange-Act-Assert paradigm?

Tags: c#, exception, testing, nunit

In nUnit 3, there's been considerable changes made, among which the *[ExpectedException](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.6.3)* has been dropped to be replaced by the assertion model.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014534/1525840) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893670/1525840) example but the recommendation is to use *Assert.That()* instead so I want to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897450/1525840) as shown below.

```
//Arrange
string data = "abcd";
//Act
ActualValueDelegate<object> test = () => data.MethodCall();
//Assert
Assert.That(test, Throws.TypeOf<ExceptionalException>());
```

However, I'd like to test the assert for a number of different parameters but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried the following.

```
List<List<Stuff>> sets = new[] { 0, 1, 2 }
  .Select(_ => Enumerable.Repeat(new Stuff(_), _).ToList())
  .ToList();
Assert.Throws(() => Transform.ToThings(new List<Stuff>()));
```

The above works as to creating the list of lists, as desired and testing the *Transform.Stuff()* call. However, I haven't figured out a way to **plug *sets* into things**.

Is it possible? Where are the examples? (Most of the searches drown in nUnit 2.x and on the official documentation site, I see nothing that helps me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using the [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute to define the inputs to your method:

```
[TestCaseSource("StuffSets")]
public void ToThings_Always_ThrowsAnException(List<Stuff> set)
{
    // Arrange
    // Whatever you need to do here...

    // Act
    ActualValueDelegate<object> test = () => Transform.ToThings(set);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(test, Throws.TypeOf<SomeKindOfException>());
}

public static IEnumerable<List<Stuff>> StuffSets = 
{
    get 
    {
        return new[] { 0, 1, 2 }
            .Select(_ => Enumerable.Repeat(new Stuff(_), _).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
};
```

This will invoke `ToThings_Always_ThrowsAnException` once for each `List<Stuff>` that is returned from `StuffSets` (here, three times).

Comment: It surprises me that the input isn't brought in from the parentheses at *test = () => ...* instead. Am I totally off feeling that it's the lambda expression that should be able to produce the input to the transforming method?

Comment: Maybe, but it is a design decision the NUnit team made; they chose the `TestCaseSource`, `ValueSource`, and other ways of parameterizing tests with input instead of creating an API on `Assert` to do it.

Comment: Answer accepted and +1'ed. I have one minor follow-up, though. When you say that the nUnit team made a design decision, is it something you infer from the circumstances or is there an actual source of that information? Rationale behind it? I want to emphasize that I by no means question your statement. I'm just curious.

Comment: I only say that because of course one *could* implement it in the way you describe in your question, but that's just not how the NUnit team implemented it.  The `TestCaseSource` was introduced so long ago I doubt I could dig enough to find any online record of why they went down the road they did.