# Replacement for MatchType?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0, expected-exception

The new NUnit Version 3.x does not support `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` any longer. There is an `Assert.Throws<MyException>()` instead. Probably a better logical concept. But I failed to find any replacement for the old good `MatchType` - is there any? `MyException` can be thrown with a number of parameters, in NUnit 2.x I could compare the exception message for the containment of a certain text fragment to know which parameter was used (and, certainly, I am not going to have dozens of exception classes instead of the just logical one). How can this be handled with NUnit 3.x? I was unable to find a hint.

With NUnit 2.x, I would do the following:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(ExpectedException=typeof(MyException),  ExpectedMessage="NON_EXISTENT_KEY", MatchType=MessageMatch.Contains)]
public void DeletePatient_PatientExists_Succeeds()
 {
    Person p    = new Person("P12345", "Testmann^Theo", new DateTime(1960, 11, 5), Gender.Male);
    MyDatabase.Insert(p);

    MyDatabase.Delete(p.Key);

    // Attemp to select from a database with a non-existent key.
    // MyDatabase throws an exception of type MyException with "NON_EXISTENT_KEY" within the message string,
    // so that I can distinguish it from cases where MyException is thrown with different message strings.
    Person p1   = MyDatabase.Select(p.Key);
 }
```

How can I do anything similar with NUnt 3.x?

Please consider what I mean: the means that NUnit provides for, are not sufficient to recognize the parameters with which the exception was thrown, so this is a different question.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a clear example of a test you're trying to port. Your situation is unclear to me at the moment.

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve] instead of putting it in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use nunit's Assert.Throws method or Expected Exception attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014461/should-i-use-nunits-assert-throws-method-or-expected-exception-attribute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NUnit: Assert.Throws](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609536/nunit-assert-throws)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it looks, a possibility does exist (and even a sharper one than the aforementioned) to provide for this functionality, albeit not in NUnit 3 itself, but in `FluentAssertions` (http://www.fluentassertions.com/). There, you can do things like

```
 Action act = () => MyDatabase.Select(p.Key);
 act.ShouldThrow<MyException>().Where(ex => ex.Message.Contains("NON_EXISTENT_KEY"));
```

For all my practical purposes this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<MyException>(()=> MyDatabase.Select(p.Key));
StringAssert.Contains("NON_EXISTENT_KEY", ex.Message);
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Assert.Throws check thrown exception of expected type, and returns instance of the exception. In next line StringAssert checks, if expected string contains in Exception.Message.  Exactly the same result as in your comment by FluentAssertions, but everything by NUnit 3.

Comment: OK, I may have misunderstood StringAssert.

Comment: More info about StringAssert in NUnit 3: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/String-Assert

Comment: In my case, Google sent me here and I didn't know what `MatchType` did (updating old code). Would have been nice to get an explanation that connected `MatchType` and `StringAssert.Contains`.